# Doctrine2, Symfony2. Oracle Error:Class has no field or association named user_id

Tags: php, oracle, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm attempting to return data from a simple query but I get the following error:

> Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\ORM\Query\QueryException: "[Semantical
>   Error] line 0, col 63 near 'user_id = :u': Error: Class
>   \Bundle\MyBundle\Entity\User\Users has no field or association named
>   user_id" at …../doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/Query/QueryException.php
>   line 49

The Entity:

```
    /**
* Users
*
* @ORM\Table(name="company.users")
* @ORM\Entity
*/
class Users
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="user_id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @ORM\SequenceGenerator(sequenceName="company.user_id_seq")
     */
    private $userId;
```

The Call in the Controller:

```
$query = $em->createQuery(
    'SELECT u
    FROM MyBundle:User\Users u
    WHERE u.user_id = :user_id'
)->setParameter('user_id', 48201);

$users = $query->getResult();
```

Answer (score 2):

While using DQL you need to forget about SQL. You should use column names defined in Entity not in database - use `userId` instead of `user_id`:

```
$query = $em->createQuery(
    'SELECT u
    FROM MyBundle:Users u
    WHERE u.userId = :user_id'
)->setParameter('user_id', 48201);
```

I'm also not sure about `MyBundle:User\Users` syntax. Why don't you use `MyBundle:Users` ?

Comment: i tried it both ways.  userId and user_id with the same results.

Comment: do you have ``use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;`` at the top of your entity file?

Comment: Yes, I have the Doctrine\ORM\Mapping statement.  As far as using MyBundle:User\Users.....User is a subfolder of the folder that contains all the Entity categories.  So There's a Client folder, product folder, etc.  which each contain Entity classes for those categories

Comment: so are you saying that when you change in query ``user_id`` to ``userId`` you get the same result? (meaning that error message says about ``user_id`` missing)

Comment: Yes, the same exact error accept it says 'has no field or association named userId